# Board purchasing stadium twice, is it a bug or what does it mean?

Tags: football-manager-2017

After last season, the board asked me if buying the stadium was a good idea, and I agreed with it. Now, after the season, the board asked me the same question again. I didn't want to mess with the board, so I agreed with them.

Now, I have the following two active board requests:

[image: Board buying stadium twice]

Is this a bug, or does it actually mean something? I mean, could the first one be a partial purchase or something?

---

I would like to add that now, a few seasons later, I still have the option to ask the board to *buy the stadium*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question here.

I just googled this again, and it turned out some other people having the exact same problem. There are two threads on this on the SI games forum:

- https://community.sigames.com/topic/392666-club-buying-stadium-twice/
- https://community.sigames.com/topic/394445-buying-stadium-issue/

The last of these two threads has a quite lengthy disucssion, these are the first two post:

> my fc Halifax board have asked me twice to buy the stadium out right but each time the process has got to the completion stage but seems to never have happened and then they ask me again about buying it, is this a common bug?

And the answer from an Sports Interactive employed:

> Could you please upload a save from before the stadium buying fails to complete? We can then take a look at this for you.

So, yes, I am perfectly comfortable to say that **it is a bug**. As far as I know, it has not yet been resolved, and it doesn't seem to be that common.